# incrementing a number followed by a letter. eg A1, A2, A3 only. Under process builder formula field

Tags: process-builder, string, increment

I'm using the process builder for a certain task. Which will check a field of a record,

if it's value is A1, it will create a new record and set it to A2,

if A2 then set it to A3, and if A3 then set it to A1.

A1, A2, A3 are the only values that should be there.

im planning to use this code inside the formula field of the process builder

Comment: Hi Niveth, can you please elaborate more the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Account].Name  = 'A1' in one criteria and then create a record with account name as A2..then go next criteria if its not A1 and check for A2 and create A3 record immediate action ..then check for A3 and create a record of A1

Hope this will work for you.

Thanks,
Ashwini

Comment: Please Mark as best answer if formula works for you

Comment: It's not appropriate on Stack Exchange to ask for upvotes or answer acceptance in most situations. If the question sits unaccepted for a long time, perhaps, but that's not the case here.

Comment: this is what i came up with, but was looking for a more efficient way. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sure @DavidReed

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula like this in a "create new record" action:

```
CASE([Account].TextField__c 
, 'A1', 'A2'
, 'A2', 'A3'
, 'A3', 'A1'
, 'A1')
```

This is assuming that if the text field is anything other than A1, A2 or A3, (ie if it's blank), the formula will create a record with value of A1